# Make g++ warn on uninitialized POD member variable

Tags: c++, g++, warnings

Is there a way to print a warning if you forget to declare in ctor initialization list a member POD?  I'm looking through docs and can't find anything. g++-4.4 here.

Answer (score 5):

You can enable `-Weffc++` to get a heap of ridiculous warnings, including every single non-ctor-initialized member.

To check for *actual* UB, use valgrind.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the option `-Wuninitialized` (and also `-Wall`).
However, It only warns if the Uninitialized type is being used.

Also, Ofcourse you can use other softwares like **[Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)** and [**Cppcheck**](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppcheck/index.php?title=Main_Page) to determine Uninitialized types.